# Tooling REST API CalloutException Read timed out

Tags: rest-api, callout, tooling-api

We've got an issue regarding Salesforce improperly cleaning out `FlowElementTestCoverage` records, leaving over a million "stranded" on an old/inactive Flow Version. This is causing us to be unable to delete said Flow Version.

The object in question can only be queried/deleted via the Tooling API, and I've written the following just to test retrieval:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken);

String urlQuery = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('SELECT Id, FlowVersionId FROM FlowElementTestCoverage WHERE FlowVersionId = \'[myFlowVersionId]\' LIMIT 1', 'UTF-8');
req.setEndpoint('https://[domain].my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/tooling/query/?q='+urlQuery);

HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
System.debug(res.getStatus());
```

Problem is, I always get `System.CalloutException: Read timed out`. However, when I remove the WHERE clause such that the query is `SELECT Id, FlowVersionId FROM FlowElementTestCoverage LIMIT 1`, it works fine.

I guess I'm just a little lost as to how to proceed. I don't understand how adding a FlowVersionId filter would cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in thinking further about the WHERE clause specifically causing the issue, I wondered if it was a spacing issue. I edited that line to remove spaces in the SELECT and WHERE:

```
SELECT Id,FlowVersionId FROM FlowElementTestCoverage WHERE FlowVersionId=\'[myFlowVersionId]\' LIMIT 1'
```

...and it worked!

Comment: White space in the WHERE clause shouldn't be causing a time out exception.  Are they correctly URL encoding as `%20`?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I just checked and indeed, it is NOT encoding it correctly. Instead, it's doing: SELECT+Id+FROM+FlowElementTestCoverage+WHERE+FlowVersionId+%3D+%27[myFlowVersionId]%27+LIMIT+1